# Javascript/JQuery Image Picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, picker

I'm looking for JS/JQuery way to do the following
    1: Display a series of paint chips side by side along with a 'none' image
    2: When a chip is clicked
        A: Highlight it with a border to show it has been selected
        B: Change the value of a text field/perhaps a hidden field to the appropriate color name
            (so the images should be flagged indigo, solaria, etc and update accordingly)

I had found this post on Stackoverflow, but couldn't get it working: [jQuery image picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339013/jquery-image-picker)

And here's my current code based on the above link

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('div#image_container img').click(function(){
    // set the img-source as value of image_from_list
    $('input#image_from_list').val( $(this).attr("src") );
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="images/vermillion.jpg" />
    <img src="images/riverway.jpg" />
    <img src="images/solaria.jpg" />
</div>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input id="image_from_list" name="image_from_list" type="text" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!!

---

Well I ended up fixing the issue actually and here's the code I used

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="images/vermillion.jpg" col="red" border="0" />
    <img src="images/riverway.jpg" col="blue" border="0" />
    <img src="images/solaria.jpg" col="yellow" border="0" />
</div>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input id="image_from_list" name="image_from_list" type="text" value=""  />
</form>
<script>
    $("div#image_container img").click(function () {
        $("div#image_container img").attr("border","0");
        $(this).attr("border","4");
        $("input#image_from_list").val($(this).attr("col"));
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I get what your question is, can you clarify?

Comment: I want to display 3 images - when a image is clicked I want the value of a form field updated to reflect that click.  If possible a border around the current image would be nice as well.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not work because you forgot to enclose your jquery statements in $(document).ready block. Your updated code works because you moved the script block to the bottom but technically you should enclose it in document.ready

Here is a working version

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#image_container img').click(function(){
    //remove border on any images that might be selected
    $('#image_container img').removeClass("img_border")
    // set the img-source as value of image_from_list
    $('#image_from_list').val( $(this).attr("src") );
      $('#data_value').val( $(this).attr("id") );
     // $('#data_value').val( $(this).data("options").color );

    //add border to a clicked image
    $(this).addClass("img_border")
});

})
</script>
<style>
    .img_border {
        border: 2px solid red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="images/vermillion.jpg" id="vermillion"/>
    <img src="images/riverway.jpg" id="riverway"/>
    <img src="images/solaria.jpg" id="solaria"/>

</div>

<form action="" method="get">
    <input id="image_from_list" name="image_from_list" type="text" value="" />
     <input id="data_value"  type="text" value="" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! I'm a newb with JS/JQuery so was trying to piece things together from examples online =)

Answer (score 6):

I know this has been already answered but I developed a plugin that solves this exact problem and is pretty well maintained.

http://rvera.github.com/image-picker/

Comment: Can your plugin be used to store image urls in a hidden form field as a list of delimited urls? Nothing was mentioned of this in the docs...

Comment: Sorry, the plugin doesn't do that.

Answer (score 2):

Updated the code I finally used in the question, but here it as well

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="images/vermillion.jpg" col="red" border="0" />
    <img src="images/riverway.jpg" col="blue" border="0" />
    <img src="images/solaria.jpg" col="yellow" border="0" />
</div>
<form action="" method="get">
    <input id="image_from_list" name="image_from_list" type="text" value=""  />
</form>
<script>
    $("div#image_container img").click(function () {
        $("div#image_container img").attr("border","0");
        $(this).attr("border","4");
        $("input#image_from_list").val($(this).attr("col"));
    }); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```